# Android - how to set a foreground image that is centered on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been googling for a solution, and I only find solutions where `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` is used, and I am using `LinearLayout`.

What I am trying to do is display an image in the foreground saying "please wait" before some things load on the page. And I am trying to have that image be centered, and not shift the other page elements around...so for that I guess I need it in the foreground, right?

How could I do this?  Right now I have this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/please_wait"
    android:foregroundGravity="center|fill_horizontal" />
```

But it is not centering the image and isn't putting it in the foreground.

Here is the whole xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<include android:id="@+id/header"
         layout="@layout/header"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>    

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/please_wait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/please_wait"
        android:foregroundGravity="center|fill_horizontal"
         />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/problem_loading_prompt"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Getting the business(es) you are planning. They are stored in a database that is constantly backed up so you do not lose your work."
    />          

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="17sp"> 
    </ListView>

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_problem_ok"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue" 
    android:text="Plan a New Business"
    android:layout_marginTop ="15dp"    
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: could u paste to whole xml file pls..

Comment: @Rahmathullah M Pulikkal just pasted it - thanks :)

Comment: so the other components will be hidden while loading. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way to display "please wait" message is just create Dialog. Here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html you have good tutorial how to create a dialog. I think you can use AlertDialog with custom view, or ProgressDialog, because it has beauty spinner.

Dialogs you call from java code, not from xml, so Dialog isn't strict answer to your question, but I think that it is close to what you want.

If you really want to do something like that in xml, I think you have to use FrameLayout, because it is designed to do something like that. Or you could try use RelativeLayout.

EDIT:
Here is sample code for create AlertDialog with your image:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom); 
dialog.show(); //this will show dialog 
dialog.dismiss(); //now dialog will disapear
```

And here you have xml file named custom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/please_wait"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course you can use different layout also.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <Your existing stuff />  
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:centerInParent="true" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way you can keep the whole layout you did until now, and the `RelativeLayout` will nicely put your image on top of everything. If you don't need the `ImageView` anymore, just call

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE /*or View.GONE */);
```

Comment: does it have to be in a relative layout? Mine is using a linear layout, and the suggestion you made, which I like, is unfortunately not working in a linear layout for some reason.  Any thoughts what is the best approach here? Should I just switch to a relative layout?

Comment: Hi! People recommend you the RelativeLayout, because it allows you to put things on top each other. A LinearLayout will never put its children on top of each other. I tried to write the example so, that you wont have to rewrite your existing layout. You simply need to wrap your existing application layout in a LinearLayout, add your ImageView after that, and put everything in a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center" >                <--- like this

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foregroundGravity="center|fill_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

it works for me.

Comment: I tried it like this with the android:gravity="center" but it had a strange effect on my screen and slightly shifted things around, but still didn't put the image in the foreground, and centered.